# GAE, Cloud SQL and run_in_transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, task-queue, google-cloud-sql

I'm using GAE with Cloud SQL.

I can't seem to see this mentioned in the documentation so I thought I would ask just to clarify my understanding.

Is the standard method of grouping transactions i.e:

```
def do_something_in_transaction(...)
  update my CloudSQL database record
  taskqueue.add(url='/path/to/my/worker', transactional=True)
  ...

db.run_in_transaction(do_something_in_transaction, ....)
```

Assumed to work for cloud SQL?

Also can I also update / insert / delete multiple records (i.e. as many as I need) during the run_in_transaction call?

i.e:

```
def do_something_in_transaction(...)
   x_id = insert record into table x
   update table y record with x_id
   insert record into table a
   insert record into table b
   … etc
  taskqueue.add(url='/path/to/my/worker', transactional=True)
```

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

Given that it's part of the db component, I think run_in_transaction is specific to the datastore.

For CloudSQL, use SQL transaction commands START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, ROLLBACK.

Comment: Yeah true. Thanks. Hopefully I'll get a response from the GAE team as well.